# How to pass variable that contains path file as parameter to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, uri, parameter-passing

Can someone help me with this issue? I'm new in **codeigniter** and **stack overflow**.
So I have this controller that renders my website pages:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

public function view($page = 'home') {

if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')) {

show_404();

} else  {

$this->load->view('templates/menu');
$this->load->view('pages/'. $page);

}

}
```

This method loads views that are placed into the 'pages' directory and it works for all views inside this directory. Now the menu view contains a link that should load 'test' view placed in pages/admin/test.php.

`<a href="<?php echo site_url('pages/view/admin/test')?>">`

This anchor doesn't work, anyway, because of the URI that is incorrectly passed by the menu view to the controller.
How can I ask my controller that it has to load that view?
Many thanks to everyone that will help me!

Comment: when you go and click the link, what does it say? elaborate _This anchor doesn't work._

Comment: it shows a 404 error!

Comment: then you need to check whether the file exists!

Comment: The file exists but how can i pass the file path by URI?

Comment: is `admin` another sub folder and `test` is the php file?

Comment: yes!! admin is a subfolder of pages (that is a subfolder of views), and test is the php file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make double check of locations if contain required file

```
if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php') && 
     ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/admin/'.$page.'.php')) {
    show_404();
} else {
    $view = file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php');
    $viewadmin = file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/admin/'.$page.'.php');
    $this->load->view('templates/menu');
    if ($view) {
        $this->load->view('pages/'. $page);
    } else {
        $this->load->view('pages/admin/'. $page);            
    }
}
```

But personally, I would separate those in second method that would check for subfolder file exists just to avoid name collition issue.